# 8-segmet LED's on Adafruit Trinket

Tags: led, display

I would like to have an array of eight 7- and [8-segment LED](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-d4ug4mb_Cw0/T6y7ZVrbb-I/AAAAAAAAAsE/nj6Tfp0j26s/s400/SEV1.jpg) numerical displays on my Adafruit Trinket.
I know that there are some prebuilt arrays of 4 LED's. So 2 in array would do just fine.
However, my Adafruit Trinket doesn't have enough ports for that. I have heard something about connecting it to a small piece of controlling hardware that makes me able to have way less ports in need.
What is the appropriate way of connecting a lot of those LED's on only a few ports on a micro controller?

My ideal output would be as follow: 
88 88:88:88 or maybe 88 88.88.88
So ideally there would be a small space between the first group of 2 digits and the rest.
Basically, the last 6 digits will represent a time in minutes, seconds and hundreds of seconds.

Comment: Do you have to use LED's?  An LCD with a serial interface would be a better match for that board.  You can solve the problem with an I/O expander, but consider simply switching to something built with a full size ATmega328p chip, like one of the mini or micro boards - which would get you both sufficient I/Os and more program resources.

Comment: The screen should be visible while the sun is blasting on it. That is why I opted for those. Is there even a better solution for outdoor displays?

Comment: Bright sunlight readability is a tough enough requirement that you should pick your specific display first, and then pick a board to drive it.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a display? I don't have enough knowledge (in fact very little) to be able to pick the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

For LED displays, I advise using a [MAX7219](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf).

This circuit:

- can manage up to 8 digits (7-segments + 1 LED for DP or colon separator) or up to 64 LEDs
- needs only 3 pins to manage display
- can be daisy-chained if you need to interface with more than 64 LEDs
- requires only 1 resistor to be fully functional
- is easily supported on Arduino with [this library](http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/LedControl.zip)

I have used it in several circuits and happy with it.

Note that there also [other libraries](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LEDMatrix) that support this circuit but I haven't used them.

This circuit has only one downside: its price (about $10 each); but the price is counter-balanced by its simplicity and the fact you don't need any additional component (e.g. transistors) besides a simple resistor.

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer! I will look into it this weekend. Looks perfect for what I need!